# How we use Rethinkdb in react native

Tags: react-native, rethinkdb

There anyone know.I want use rethinkdb in react-native so how can i use firstly i didnt have any backend server like node and express and flask.without server i want to use rethinkdb in react-native.

## rethinkdb and #react-native

Answer (score 0):

RethinkDB is a server software. You can't run the database on a client device, only on a backend server.

If you need a local database i suggest you look into sqlite. If you're on iOS exclusively you could also use Core Data. There are no-sql db engines for local use as well, like [realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-database). This might be a helpful [article](https://www.simform.com/react-native-database-selection-guide/).